# Error sintaxis mysql con java --preparedstatement--

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy realizando una consulta de mysql con java y me devuelve el siguiente error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1"

He lanzado varios prints para ver que puede ser

```
public boolean CochesobtenerporID(Coches c) {   
if (!abrirConexion())
    if(!abrirConexion())
    {
        return false;
    }
    boolean CochesobtenerporID = true;
    
    try {
                    
        PreparedStatement ps = conexion.prepareStatement("SELECT *  FROM VEHICULOS WHERE ID = ?");
        int id = c.getId();
        ps.setInt(1,id);
        System.out.println("aaaaa");
        System.out.println(ps);
            
        
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery("SELECT *  FROM VEHICULOS WHERE ID = ?");
        System.out.println("bbbbb");
        System.out.println(rs);
        while (rs.next()) {     
        
            System.out.print(rs.getString("matricula"));
            System.out.print("  --  ");
            System.out.print(rs.getString("marca"));
            System.out.print("  --  ");
            System.out.print(rs.getString("modelo"));
            System.out.print("  --  ");
            System.out.print(rs.getString("color"));
            System.out.println("");
            }
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("consulta. " );
        CochesobtenerporID = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("SELECT *  FROM 'VEHICULOS' WHERE ID = ?");
        System.out.println(c.getId());
        System.out.println("marca");
        System.out.println(c.getMarca());
    }
    return CochesobtenerporID;
}
```

y me devuelve lo siguiente:

> Introduce el id del coche que quieres consultar  2 Conexión
> establecida aaaaa com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement: SELECT *
> FROM VEHICULOS WHERE ID = 2 consulta.
> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
> version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1 SELECT *  FROM
> 'VEHICULOS' WHERE ID = ? 2 marca null
>
> Escribe una de las siguientes opciones
>
> 1. Añadir nuevo coche.
> 2. Borrar coche por id.
> 3. Consultar coche por id.
> 4. Listado de coches.
> 5. Exportar coches a archivo de texto.
> 6. Modificar coche por id.
> 7. Terminar el programa.  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
>    at
>    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
>    at
>    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
>    at
>    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1200)
>    at
>    modelo.persistencia.DaoVehiculos.CochesobtenerporID(DaoVehiculos.java:217)
>    at prueba.Concesionario.main(Concesionario.java:120)

Answer (score 0):

Tu *PreparedStatement* está bien, el problema es que al hacer *executeQuery* le pasas una nueva query que no está parametrizada.

Por algún motivo, *PreparedStatement* extiende *Statement* así que tiene un método *executeQuery(String)* que en realidad es de *Statement*. Ese es el que estás ejecutando, pero es lo mismo que si usaras el método de *Statement*. Y ese método no hace substitución del placeholder (?).

Lo que tienes que hacer es usar el método propio de *PreparedStatement*, *executeQuery()* (sin parámetros)

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```